# How to pick multiple imageURIs from recent images?

Tags: android, kotlin

I start an intent to get URIs of images. System start (I think Files) with recent folder, but I need start it with recent images.

I use this code:

```
    val chooserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
    chooserIntent.type = "image/*"
    launcherPickImage.launch(chooserIntent)
```

It starts with recent folder, but I want to start it with recent images, what can I can choose from top left corner of system chosen app.
I tried EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, it works fine on physical folders, but I think recent images is an app built in thing...

Answer (score 0):

you can use this
PickMultipleVisualMedia(5)
5 represents the number of media items you can pick

```
val pickMultipleMedia =
        registerForActivityResult(PickMultipleVisualMedia(5)) { uris ->
    // Callback is invoked after the user selects media items or closes the
    // photo picker.
    if (uris.isNotEmpty()) {
        Log.d("PhotoPicker", "Number of items selected: ${uris.size}")
    } else {
        Log.d("PhotoPicker", "No media selected")
    }
}
```

and to launch it

```
pickMultipleMedia.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly))
```

The photo picker is available on devices that run Android 11 (API level 30) or higher.

And also update the androidx.activity to the latest version.

```
androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Intent.ACTION_PICK` instead of `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null)
intent.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "image/*")
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
resultLauncher.launch(intent)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`PickVisualMediaRequest`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker):

Unfortunately, Photo picker runs only on **Android 11 (API level 30) or higher**

```kotlin
val pickMultipleMedia =
        registerForActivityResult(PickMultipleVisualMedia(5)) { uris ->
    // handle result
}

pickMultipleMedia.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(PickVisualMedia. ImageOnly))
```